# Rails 5, rails c data output display in an in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Something strange is happening in my views, in a rails 5 app. Everytime I display a view I get output from My console displaying in my index views

I have searched everything online and cannot find a solution to stop it from displaying...

index action in my controller:

```
def index
    if params[:category].blank?
      @books = Book.all.order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
      @books = Book.where(:category_id => @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end
```

Whats appearing in my view

```
Jaws
Michael Collins
Messi
The Assination of Jesse James
Pocket Reference JavaScript
A Game of Thrones: The Illustrated Edition: A Song of Ice and Fire: Book 3
The Lion The Witch and The Wardrobe
The Rise of The Islamic State
1984
The Principles of Objected Oriented JavaScript
Dracula
No Country for Old Men
Game of Thrones: A Storm of Swords; Steel and Snow, Book 3, Part 1

[#<Book id: 19, title: "Jaws", description: "kdmfvkmvlsf", author: "Stephen King", created_at: "2018-07-22 22:14:54", updated_at: "2018-07-22 22:14:54", user_id: 1, category_id: 5>, #<Book id: 18, title: "Michael Collins ", description: " jnkefjn", author: "Tim Pat Coogan", created_at: "2018-07-22 22:09:34", updated_at: "2018-07-22 22:09:34", user_id: 1, category_id: 3>, #<Book id: 17, title: "Messi", description: "SDNFKJVVSFNVJKNVFJ", author: "Guillem Balague ", created_at: "2018-07-22 20:54:38", updated_at: "2018-07-22 20:54:38", user_id: 2, category_id: 3>, #<Book id: 16, title: "The Assination of Jesse James ", description: "jsdnfvjksnvjnfvfsnjvsn jdfnvjnsfvkjnvkjnfdj jefnvj...", author: "Jesse James", created_at: "2018-07-22 20:37:03", updated_at: "2018-07-22 20:37:03", user_id: 2, category_id: 4>, #<Book id: 15, title: "Pocket Reference JavaScript", description: "erfveafv", author: "fvsfv", created_at: "2018-07-22 20:29:01", updated_at: "2018-07-22 20:29:01", user_id: 2, category_id: 1>, #<Book id: 14, title: "A Game of Thrones: The Illustrated Edition: A Song...", description: "ADFVFV", author: "George R. R. Martin", created_at: "2018-07-22 17:06:24", updated_at: "2018-07-22 17:06:24", user_id: 2, category_id: 2>, #<Book id: 13, title: "The Lion The Witch and The Wardrobe", description: "jsfnvjfnv", author: "Someone", created_at: "2018-07-22 15:59:12", updated_at: "2018-07-22 15:59:12", user_id: 2, category_id: 2>, #<Book id: 12, title: "The Rise of The Islamic State ", description: "fdvmsdfkvmfmskdfvm sdfmvsfdmv", author: "Patrick Cockburn", created_at: "2018-07-22 15:56:06", updated_at: "2018-07-22 15:56:06", user_id: 2, category_id: 4>, #<Book id: 11, title: "1984", description: "JSDNFVJFNVSFNVSLKFJNSJVNJFNVVJFSNDJ", author: "George Orwell", created_at: "2018-07-22 15:22:05", updated_at: "2018-07-22 15:22:05", user_id: 2, category_id: 8>, #<Book id: 10, title: "The Principles of Objected Oriented JavaScript ", description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing a...", author: "Walter Isaacson", created_at: "2018-07-22 15:18:05", updated_at: "2018-07-22 15:18:05", user_id: 2, category_id: 1>, #<Book id: 9, title: "Dracula ", description: "Bram Stoker's Dracula is a 1992 American gothic ho...", author: "Bram Stroker", created_at: "2018-07-22 14:48:44", updated_at: "2018-07-22 14:48:44", user_id: 2, category_id: nil>, #<Book id: 8, title: "No Country for Old Men", description: "Cormac McCarthy was born in Rhode Island. He later...", author: "Cormac McCarthy", created_at: "2018-07-22 14:46:23", updated_at: "2018-07-22 14:46:23", user_id: 1, category_id: nil>, #<Book id: 7, title: "Game of Thrones: A Storm of Swords; Steel and Snow...", description: "Megalodon (Carcharocles megalodon), an extinct spe...", author: "George R. R. Martin", created_at: "2018-07-22 14:41:38", updated_at: "2018-07-22 14:41:38", user_id: 1, category_id: nil>]
```

Comment: Can you add your view code here. Most probably while iterating over your book collections you are printing them on views.for e.g. In case of erb use <% instead of this <%= while iterating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have something similar to this in your view:

```
<%= @books.each do |book| %>
```

remove the `=`

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
```